# Как уменишить размер PDF файла на стороне клиента перед отправкой на сервер ?

Tags: javascript, pdf, сжатие

Существует ли способ уменьшить размер PDF файла, возможно с потерей качеcтва последнего, но на сторое клиента, с помощью Javascript?

Моя идея состоит в том чтобы

- конвертировать страницы PDF в картинки
- затем сжать эти картинки до опреленого качества
- собрать в PDF обратно.

Реализуемо ли это на JS и возможно уже существует решение или библиотека которые делают это?

P.S. Файл должен оставаться в PDF формате и открываться, то есть не быть архивом вроде zip...

Answer (score 0):

Получилось такое решение :

```js
$(() => {

  var upload = document.getElementById('fileUpload')
  upload.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {

    compressedFile = null;
    if (evt.target.files.length > 0) {

      var file = evt.target.files[0];
      if (isPDF(file.name)) {

       
        fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (evt) => {

          //качество картинки определяет финальный размер файла от 0 до 1.
          SlicePDF(evt, fileReader, 0.5)
            .then((imagesInBas64) => {

              //compressed pdf
              let dataUriOfCompressedFile = Combine(imagesInBas64);
              download(dataUriOfCompressedFile, 'compressed.pdf');
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      } else {
        alert("Not a pdf file. Please choose a PDF")
      }
    }

  });
});

function isPDF(name) {
  // File and Blob are not supported
  var ext = name.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
  ext = ext.toLowerCase();
  if (ext === "pdf")
    return true;
  return false;
}

function ConvertPxToMM(pixels) {
  return Math.floor(pixels * 0.264583);
}

function SlicePDF(ev, fileReader, quality) {
  //  console.log(ev);
  const deferred = $.Deferred();
  PDFJS.getDocument(fileReader.result)
    .then((pdf) => {

      const images = [];

      for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
        pdf.getPage(i).then((page) => {

          var scale = 1;
          let viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          let canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;
          let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          // Render PDF page into canvas context                        
          var task = page.render({
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            })
            .then(() => {
              images[i - 1] = {
                data: canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality),
                height: canvas.height,
                width: canvas.width
              };
              if (Object.keys(images).length == pdf.numPages) {
                deferred.resolve(images);
              }
            });
        });
      };


    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

  return deferred.promise();
};


function Combine(images) {

  var doc = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

    let w = ConvertPxToMM(images[i].width);
    let h = ConvertPxToMM(images[i].height);
    var orientation = w > h ? 'l' : 'p';

    if (i == 0) {
      doc = new jsPDF(orientation, 'mm', [w, h]);
    } else {
      doc.addPage(w, h);
    }
    doc.addImage(images[i].data, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
  }
  //Possibles values : dataurl, datauristring, bloburl, blob, arraybuffer, ('save', filename)
  return doc.output('datauristring');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/downloadjs/1.4.7/download.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.8.497/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="btn btn-default" />
```

PS. Этот метод имеет существенный недостаток. Если исходный файл pdf состоит из векторной графики или текста, то при переводе страницы в растр мы рискуем получить размер файла больше чем был изначально.

Тем не менее если в пдф много картинок, как в моем случае, то размер уменьшится.